# fix records that contain the same field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Incorrect records were created due to an error in the system.

***Current :***

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5cb48b1875aca0626d0272db"),
   "similiarModels" : [
                 ObjectId("5cb48b1875aca0626d0272db"), -> the same as the _id field of the object, it must be removed from the array
                 ObjectId("9fg48f5325qwa0436h9433ae")
    ]
    "topModel" : ObjectId("5cb48b1875aca0626d0272db")  -> the same as the _id field of the object, should be removed
}
```

***I want to :***

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5cb48b1875aca0626d0272db"),
   "similiarModels" : [
                 ObjectId("9fg48f5325qwa0436h9433ae")
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have compass ? to just edit it with GUI Tool or Do you use ORM ?

Comment: Why would you want to remove `"topModel"` from the collection?  Or maybe `"topModel"` doesn't mean what I expect it does?  FYI, the `ObjectId` you want to keep isn't a valid `ObjectId`.

Comment: Does `topModel` get removed under *all* conditions?   Or only when it is the same value as the `_id` ?

Comment: So the logic is, if a document does not have a `"topModel"` field, then it is the `"topModel"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution.   Note the use of the pipeline form of `update` and the `$$REMOVE` special value.

```js
db.foo.update(
    {},  // no filter; get all docs                                                           
    [ // use pipeline form of update expression for greater flexibility!
        {$set: {
          'similarModels': {$setDifference:['$similarModels', ['$_id'] ]},
          'topModel': {$cond: [
            {$eq:['$topModel','$_id']},  // if                                                
            '$$REMOVE',  // then get rid of field                                             
            '$topModel'  // else set it back to original                                      
          ]}
        }}
    ],
    {multi:true}
);
```

Alternatively, one can use the "merge onto self" capability introduced in v4.4.  This allows `aggregate` to act as a giant `update`.  See caveat in comments below:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    // EXACT same expression as pipeline update above; nice.
    {$set: {
        'similarModels': {$setDifference: ['$similarModels', ['$_id'] ]},
        'topModel': {$cond: [
            {$eq:['$topModel','$_id']},  // if                                                
            '$$REMOVE',  // then get rid of field                                             
            '$topModel'  // else set it back to original                                      
        ]}
    }},

    // Sadly, the whenMatched:'merge' option will not "unset" fields; it only
    // adds or overwrites fields so this approach will not work for $topModel field.                                    
    // We can, however, use whenMatched:'replace' but this might present
    // a performance issue because the entire doc, not just similarModels
    // and topModel, is being written back.                                                                
    {$merge: {
        into: "foo",
        on: [ "_id" ],
        whenMatched: "replace",
        whenNotMatched: "fail"
    }}

]);
```

Comment: Awesome!  If you want, you could have a filter like `{"$expr": {"$or": [{"similarModels": "$_id"},{"topModel": "$_id"}]}}`, which may, or may not help.

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem and I learned new things.